# distinguishing between two bluetooth devices which show up with the same name

Tags: bluetooth

I have two bluetooth (keyboard-mice) pairs and would like to be able to distinguish them in the bluetooth panel.[image]     The screenshot above shows two Logitech keyboards and two M557 mice.     Is there any way to rename them in the panel, e.g., K810-A and K801-B?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do in Blueman

`sudo apt install blueman`

Open Blueman, right click on device, then rename, it is only valid on the computer you run the commands on.

You can also use `bluetoothctl` in terminal with the `set-alias` command after connecting to one of the devices.  My test  below

```
[bluetooth]# connect AC:9B:0A:4F:CA:FF 
Attempting to connect to AC:9B:0A:4F:CA:FF
[CHG] Device AC:9B:0A:4F:CA:FF Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device AC:9B:0A:4F:CA:FF ServicesResolved: yes
[MDR-ZX770BT]# set-alias Sony-Mega
[CHG] Device AC:9B:0A:4F:CA:FF Alias: Sony-Mega
```

Comment: Fabulous, thanks very much.   I ran blueman-manager, which enabled me to rename devices, and the devices remained renamed when I ran the default bluetooth manager.       Which suggests that there is some file somewhere that contains the names, and presumably one could access the file directly?