# How to display device's alias with the Ubuntu 20.04 default bluetooth manager?

Tags: bluetooth

With Ubuntu 20.04 the names of all previously paired bluetooth remote devices and all unknown bluetooth remote devices are listed under “Settings > Bluetooth”.

[image]

I have two identical headsets (SoundBuds Flow) that show up with the same name. To better distinguish them I have tried to rename these devices (at least the names that are displayed on my main device).

I have somehow successfully renamed the bluetooth remote devices (see [“How can I change the names of paired/connected remote bluetooth devices?”](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/), but as soon as the device is reconnected, the name (or more specifically the corresponding `info` file) is overwritten.

[image]

Changing the bluetooth remote devices' names with `bt-device` [see “Changing bluetooth device name”](https://superuser.com/questions/778660/)) is not an option, since the bluetooth remote device name is read-only (see [Ubuntu Manpage: bt-device](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bt-device.1.html)). Changing the alias has no practical effect, since the Ubuntu 20.04 default bluetooth manager displays the name, not the alias.

`blueman-manager` actually displays the alias (see [distinguishing between two bluetooth devices which show up with the same name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045755/)), but I would prefer a solution with the Ubuntu 20.04 default bluetooth manager.