# How to get Gnome bluetooth manager to use device alias instead of device name?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, bluetooth

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.15.0-67-generic
DE: GNOME 3.36.5
```

I have several bluetooth devices that have the same model name.

It is difficult to manage them through Gnome's default bluetooth manager GUI, because Gnome's bluetooth manager does not respect/use device aliases.

I 'renamed' the devices through Blueman, and confirmed Blueman has changed the device aliases, but the Gnome bluetooth manager device list is unchanged.

I've tried:

- `bluetoothctl set-alias my_desired_device_name`
- renaming device in Blueman
- deleting `/var/lib/bluetooth/*/device-mac`
- deleting `/var/lib/bluetooth/<controller-mac>/cache`
- `service bluetooth restart`

Nothing has made a difference in the Gnome BT gui.
Blueman respects aliases, but not gnome BT manager.

How can I make it so the Gnome BT manager gui uses device aliases like Blueman?

[image]

[image]

**Related threads:**

- [How to change Bluetooth broadcast device name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/80960)

  - None of the answers worked for me
- [How to display device's alias with the Ubuntu 20.04 default bluetooth manager?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1351876/601020)

  - Similar question; no solutions/answers

Comment: This will  https://superuser.com/questions/1696482/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-a-device-by-its-alias-in-bluetoothctl See the script "How can I make it so the Gnome BT manager gui uses device aliases like Blueman?" File a bugreport  ;-) up to then your best option is command line.